# Minimum Possible Integer After at Most K Adjacent Swaps On Digits

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a string num representing the digits of a very large integer and an integer k.

### You are allowed to swap any two adjacent digits of the integer at most k times.

Return the minimum integer you can obtain also as a string.

Example 1:

```
Input: num = "4321", k = 4
Output: "1342"
Explanation: The steps to obtain the minimum integer from 4321 with 4 adjacent swaps are shown.
```

```
Input: num = "36789", k = 1000
Output: "36789"
Explanation: We can keep the number without any swaps.
Example 4:
```

Constraints:

```
1 <= num.length <= 30000
num contains digits only and doesn't have leading zeros.
1 <= k <= 10^9
```

Here, is the code

```
class Solution {
public:
    string minInteger(string num, int k) {
        
        int n=num.length();
         string min=num;
        if (min.compare(num)>0)
            min=num;
        if (k<1)
            return 0;
        for (int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            for (int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
                if (num[i]>num[j]){
                    swap(num[i],num[j]);
                    minInteger(num,k-1,min);
                    swap(num[i],num[j]);
                }
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
        
};
```

My output ,

```
Input: num = "4321", k = 4
Output: "1234"
```

So,basically its returning a string with ascending order of digits which is not desired .
How am I supposed to correct this ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem statement says you can swap only adjacent digits while you try to swap arbitrary two digits in your code.
Instead of those two loops you should have just one that tries to swap digits at position `i` and `i+1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just use one loop to swap adjacent digits. In your code you are swapping any two digits. Maybe something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i) {
  if(num[i+1] < num[i]){
    swap(num[i+1], num[i]);
    // do your stuff
    swap(num[i+1], num[i]);
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.